# Huge HttpPost response : JSON

Tags: android, json, http, bufferedreader

I am sending an HttpPost request and getting the response in JSON format. But, as the response is so huge, I receive only a small part of the response compared to what I can see it in the browser. My code is below:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
```

As the default buffer size is  8192 characters. I just tried with giving more value but it didn't matter. So, any suggestions on this...

Comment: Are you sure you're getting only a part of the response? Remember that you can only print out a limited amount of data to the logs.

Comment: yup, I am sure it's only giving part of response.

Comment: How are you sure? What are you doing with it to check it? You should be running out of memory instead, if the response is too large.

Comment: nope, I just checked in the system browser. It will show the JSON response and I used online character counters, it gave some 200000+ characters. So, is the issue...

Comment: What is the 'system browser'?

Comment: I mean, Firefox etc. I can check it right because it is a REsT web server.

Comment: This is going round in circles, again, I ask, how do you know **for sure** that you are receiving part of the response on the Android client. Are you checking the length of the response string, or printing it straight to logs, or placing it in a TextView?

Comment: yes, I am printing the response in the logcat and which shows just part of the message...

Comment: Please refer to my first comment - there is your answer.

Comment: Is it so, I didn't know it. Thanks for the info. I will hit a try and get back.

Comment: Awesome Che Jami! you were right. It's getting whole data, but couldn't print it in the logcat. Thanks a lot...!!!

Comment: I was also stuck with same issue. Thanks Che Jami for opening my eyes :P since I was also assuming that I did not get full response from server. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that +Che Jami is onto something in the OP.

Manjunath, logcat will only output 1024 characters at a time. Have you tried outputting the String builder 1024 characters at a time? Did you check the length of the string after reading into it?

Answer (score -1):

Send only chunks (batches) of your full response in your responses and while your response is not finished use polling.

Comment: Read the following thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/woSpwMNsRdI You will probably find this to be useful.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. But, still I am not clear about my issue.

Comment: You can't receive a message in a single request which is this big, so you should have n requests. In each request a part of the message should be sent and your receiver should parse the messages into a big message. This way you won't meet this problem again, however, you will have more requests for a single message.

Comment: yes, I think this is what I should do now. I will search how to do the same request 'n' times and collect the message in 'n' parts and dump into a file.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here of how HTTP works and what polling is.